# AngularJS: Load all data at once as JSON vs. using a database and only load parts. What is better?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, mongodb

I have to display products which are stored in an ERP on a webpage. The ERP can produce an XML or JSON file which would include all products. The webpage needs functions like pagination, sorting or filtering by attributes. At the moment I think the easiest way would be to just load the entire file in AngularJS and then iterate over all items and work with that. The number of products is limited to ~500. The reason why I think this is the easiest is because the client changes the information on a daily basis in this way I don't have to write an import / synchronization process for a database.

But I am a bit worried about performance. Sorting, filtering, pagination etc. are all things that would be very fast with a database (probably MongoDB since the datastructure is quite simple).

Can I expect serious performance problems? Is this doable? Or should I put a database between ERP and frontend that does the heavy lifting?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to be sure is to test it out yourself, that is what I would do. The answer is very often, "it depends.. ". You say its around ~500 products, if each product only has a product name, then a database would be overkill. Angular is perfectly comfortable with that amount. But if each product got tons of properties and nested data, the file itself could be very large to even load on every pageload. So, it depends..

I would to this:

- Export the file from the ERP as JSON
- Create a boilerplate angular app
- Put the JSON file as a resource file
- Create a simple repeater and throw those objects out into the DOM

Now you can easily experiment with filtering, sorting, pagination and so on. Test if the browser perfomance and load time is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think there will be no performance problem on data transfer since there are only 500 elements in the JSON file. But maybe you'll experiment performance problems in showing those 500 elements with AngularJS.

Instead of pagination, you can checkout 'Infinite Scroll' with AngularJS, a good solution for result showing performance. Check this article: http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2013/07/angularjs-my-solution-to-the-ng-repeat-performance-problem/

And no, I don't agree having a database in the middle. You are trying to use it as a cache, but you'll have more problems than solutions, because since you have only 500 elements, you would not gain performance at all. And another added problem: database maintenance ;)

Cheers

Comment: I got a sample file and it was ~2MB large. So that might be a performance problem if I load that on every page load. But thanks for the link, I will check it out!

Comment: You definitely should not have to load 2MB on every page load. Instead on having a DB in the middle, you can have your JSON downloaded as a resource, and make a batch process which compares your 'cached' JSON with ERP JSON, only if information changes a lot. Then, your angular app will consume your 'cached' JSON. With this solution, you can't say for sure your info is 100% up to date, but you win on performance. There are other solutions, like web service in the middle, and asynchronous communication (with JMS for example), but these are more complex solutions. Cheers!